# Communication from UI with Event Hub via SignalR and Azure Functions

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventhub

I am working on one Azure based application where Front End (UI) is communicating with Event Hub via SignalR which sends data to Azure Functions (AF). AFs are responsible for updating the data into Cosmos Database. Once the data is inserted/ updated into Cosmos DB, a trigger (Cosmos DB Trigger) fires which then sends updated data to the EventHub so that it broadcasts the same to Front End via SignalR. We are getting very high response time in the above scenario. Besides, we cannot bypass the cosmos trigger functionality since it doesn't have any return type so UI will never know when the data has been inserted. There should be some trigger which notifies the front end that data has been updated. I am struck up with the above functionality. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: So you have a function with an eventhubtrigger that inserts data ? you don't need a cosmodb trigger, you can send back the data within the same function ???

Comment: @Thomas EventHubTrigger doesn't have any return type

Comment: Not but you can send a message to another eventhub then your app listen from this eventhub. I am pretty sure you can use output binding to eventhub using az functions